# creating a class with two possible inheritances

Tags: c++

I have a class named Radio, and I want to be able to inherit from a class named Serial, or a class named Stream, depending on how the object is created. I was thinking this could be done with templates like:

```
template<class InterfaceType>
class Radio : public InterfaceType
{
    ...
};
```

and create the object like

```
Radio<Serial> serialRadio;
Radio<Stream> streamRadio;
```

is this a good idea?

And in my implementation file where I define the functions in the class, I'm getting errors like:

```
radio.cpp:52:6: error: ‘template<class InterfaceType> class Radio’ used without template parameters
 void Radio::mavlinkReceiveByte(uint8_t data) {
      ^~~~~
```

Comment: It can be something like `template<typename T> void::Raido<T>...`

Comment: I heard that inheritance is the last resort and composition is better. Can you make a Radio class that contains either a Stream or Serial, instead of a Radio that inherits from one of them? If Stream and Serial have the same set of methods but different implementation of the methods, that should be possible.

Comment: The problem is that Stream and Serial versions of Radio have the same implementation functions, except for the interface functions, so making two different Radio classes would be repetitive.

Comment: Probably can split that to two problems: 1. data source (stream/serial) 2. interfaces (radio1/radio2). You solved 1 with inheritance. But you can also solve 1 with composition. Maybe it is ok to solve 2 with inheritance.

Comment: The error is clear: `Radio` is a `template` `class`, and the snippet you showed from your implementation isn't `template`d.  As a side note, you'll have a hard time using a separate implementation file since `Radio` is `template`d.

Comment: As to whether the design you've shown is a good idea, the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site is more appropriate for such questions of opinion. But while we're on this subject, there are those (like Sean Parent) who suggest that [inheritance should be an implementation detail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIhUE5uUFOA); not an interface detail like you've used it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess of what you want:

Test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwnlSCCxTEwC2G7BwAMAQTkKlKzOq17iC4KYvWrAei%2BqAtH6qACJMBEyqwmIS/gGxcfEJiUnJKQkeSkyCgqoAyvqGRuoA7HxWAA4iAEYMeMggHqqNqpgAHmU1yIS5%2BcYQCgSqLQCUxXxFQQ1NeuggIM6uqsCYBAD66KFMECMcJaoGBGIs6lxcBADumMsAdNxcGjzFE1Y7E7KlnpYZWbmYLkwMow8FWqtXqViaEQIMzm%2BgWS1W6zCW1Ge2Wh2OXGQCDwxDKNxO90eHhe92J3l8AVUAEkWARfgAzJgSbKpVls9mssmWOlGdqhTAaTRfbIhMIrSLiAWyMxWYWqABKTHwqEB5SqHTBlghrXatS6iuVEFFTHFokl3AAbJbVOhBCMQDaNqaopgINNZkZUAA3V22obbEok8FNL2oPDoVQsVBGLak8ouL38zUQ43OyWOsUSiRx6zjHMeHl8umOIXMb6vGWWUPhhVKnSCiuzKMxgPvCHulCiAaCwUZk1ZzBXeFrDbIntaDEcACsmhYt3zeeeVkLzDpgrlqYH7llZeyBp0K3%2BTGIhQd%2B9QDadW%2Blqq1TREggWPEyDg0QVrysvmbN2elOeBGqTI0OodPqdaoIezAnkaV4/gKXBWghNp2kBEJoQ6z6CK6Haej6EB%2Bq2QZ3o01YRs2KwtLQ5hjoGwZoao9IkKofS0qoeCOO%2B5iEuxvZUYS/D8HghF0fRUxQrMaAiN2Wi9vOU58CcJa9jxMkTnJQQOvObyoaJqiYZIIDNrG2kiRCRFmYuuavO8Hg%2BDEqgACqYHoMQcm57keVy/SqEYTAKDRbZNOekIGMYKzEBAeShTGtD%2BjmELBVhfwMOFUA5L8eD/FscUmcREQZf84VXEZQzxUF4GQcehTEJV0GRT0MX%2BqVuUQjVR4nsV0YUVRxk2eMUhDIw0hTlIpAsNI5ijag0iaAJvARHBxyyLQo0EBNA2DQA1iAU5cFctBTgALOYh0WgAnGdRSyAAHGdJ1TkNUiHaNRggEUtBXLdXCHZdXDmCdh1FGdXBjetpDTVIo2CCA5ikGtUiTYNcCwDAiCdryeAML85CUGgGNY8QKDMGwFr/aQ9KY3SxDQxAlRg5UCjHgAnmDeNGJgtIAPIsAwLMI6NWC%2BWwWNg/gBjIAQeA%2BtD/OkK0mDIFJkhSCt5C0pgDDSKrsKvfzg3E%2Bwc0CDUlTQ5Ag2oGUkuoCwMt%2BNMb6cLw/C0EUUNwXQ%2BvDaN42yxDLTXRafgWodqgZGwqgWlc5jR8xuCEExcj0KomjRmUmO/EtsUp0bq3rf6pAIIYWCE1spDbVOsOa09L0gBaH2ByHJzmBa11cAd12g370hQzDcP56QyNo12FQEDjEB4%2BnBN0HL%2BBEIT9BnMQTBlAP1cjV3k3g9ISeqGchAIIMgfB6H4fAJH0fR3neuDUXSq/JQXs16Qr03ftsiyFORRA8tRTXYd7dN5TR7kIPu8NEZbRAIDT6h0pxnSnLIf6CEqJnQtI9WQPswYQ2vhAx6XBMHd0hv3G%2BpAfTUx0ONQ6QA))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// -- Data source --

class Stream {
public:
    explicit Stream(int x) {}
    std::string get_data() { return "tweet."; }
};

class Serial {
public:
    std::string get_data() { return "chirp."; }
};

// -- Interfaces --

template<class Data_source>
class Radio {
public:
    explicit Radio(Data_source&& ds) : data_source(std::move(ds)) {}
    void nom();
private:
    Data_source data_source;
};

template <class D>
void Radio<D>::nom() {
    std::cout << data_source.get_data() << "\n";
}

template<class Data_source>
class Radio_alarm : Radio<Data_source> {
    using Base = Radio<Data_source>;
public:
    explicit Radio_alarm(Data_source&& ds)
            : Base(std::move(ds)) {}
    void nom_x10() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            std::cout << "[" << i << "]: ";
            Base::nom();
        }
    }
};

// -- Test --

int main() {
    Radio stream_r(Stream(1));
    Radio serial_r((Serial()));
    serial_r.nom();
    Radio_alarm r_alarm((Stream(1)));
    r_alarm.nom_x10();
}
```

Result:

```
chirp.
[0]: tweet.
[1]: tweet.
[2]: tweet.
[3]: tweet.
[4]: tweet.
[5]: tweet.
[6]: tweet.
[7]: tweet.
[8]: tweet.
[9]: tweet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the syntax I needed, in header file:

```
template<class InterfaceType>
class Radio : public InterfaceType
{
public:
    struct buffer
    {
        uint16_t len;
        std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> buf;
    };

    struct channels {
        uint16_t rollPWM, pitchPWM, yawPWM, throttlePWM;
    };

    buffer sendHeartbeat(uint8_t mode, uint8_t status);
    void mavlinkReceiveByte(uint8_t data);
    void mavlinkReceivePacket(uint8_t *packet);
    channels getRCChannels();

private:
    channels pwmInputs;
};
```

An example function in implementation file:

```
template<typename InterfaceType>
typename Radio<InterfaceType>::buffer Radio<InterfaceType>::sendHeartbeat(uint8_t mode, uint8_t status) {
    mavlink_message_t msg;
    uint16_t len;
    uint8_t buf[MAVLINK_MAX_PACKET_LEN];

    mavlink_msg_heartbeat_pack(SYSID, COMPID, &msg, MAV_TYPE_QUADROTOR, MAV_AUTOPILOT_GENERIC, mode, 0, status);
    len = mavlink_msg_to_send_buffer(buf, &msg);

    buffer sendBuffer;
    sendBuffer.buf = (std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]>)buf;
    sendBuffer.len = len;
    return sendBuffer;
}
```

The type in the implementation function is nasty, but it compiles... If anyone has a suggestion to make this look nicer that would be helpful.